# When using jquery ui sortable, Is there a way to programatically sort by a certain value?

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using [jquery ui sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) and inside my dom elements i have a field called "sortDate".  I am not letting people change the dates which updates this DOM element and I want to see if there is a good way to programatically sort items in a jquery ui sortable by a certain dom selector

So for example, in the below code each sortable item has a span called "itemDate".  I am programatically changing this value and I want a good way to call jquery ui sortable and say "resort all items in this list by the value in the "itemDate" span.

```
 <ul id="sortable">
   <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1<span class="itemDate">1 Apr 2014</span></li>
   <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2<span class="itemDate">21 Apr 2014</span></li>
   <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3<span class="itemDate">11 Apr 2014</span></li>
   <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4<span class="itemDate">2 Apr 2014</span></li>
</ul>
```

Does something like this exist as a continence method or do I have to hand roll this by doing it manually one by one?

Comment: just wondering whether the answer solved the issue or not.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independent of ui-sortable, you can sort the list with javascript sorting, and then re-appending the sorted list:

```
var list = $('#sortable');  
list.children().sort(function(a,b) {
  var getdat = function(el){return new Date( $(el).children('.itemDate').text())};
  return getdat(a) - getdat(b);
}).appendTo(list);
```

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/zurukive/1/watch)